# How do you give a date range then have that daterange be appended to the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I know how to generate a daterange using this code:

`pd.date_range(start='2022-10-16', end='2022-10-19')`

How do I get the daterange result above and loop through every locations in the below dataframe?

```
+----------+
| Location |
+----------+
| A        |
| B        |
| C        |
+----------+
```

This is the result I want.

```
+----------+------------+
| Location |    Date    |
+----------+------------+
| A        | 2022/10/16 |
| A        | 2022/10/17 |
| A        | 2022/10/18 |
| A        | 2022/10/19 |
| B        | 2022/10/16 |
| B        | 2022/10/17 |
| B        | 2022/10/18 |
| B        | 2022/10/19 |
| C        | 2022/10/16 |
| C        | 2022/10/17 |
| C        | 2022/10/18 |
| C        | 2022/10/19 |
+----------+------------+
```

I have spent the whole day figuring this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a cartesian product of two iterables, which is something [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) can do. Take a look at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-all-combinations-of-two-columns/).

In your case, you can try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

# Test data:
df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['Location'])
dr = pd.date_range(start='2022-10-16', end='2022-10-19')

# Create the cartesian product:
res_df = pd.DataFrame(product(df['Location'], dr), columns=['Location', 'Date'])
print(res_df)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cross join your date range and dataframe to get your desired result:

```
date_range = (pd.date_range(start='2022-10-16', end='2022-10-19')
                .rename('Date')
                .to_series())

df = df.merge(date_range, 'cross')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Location       Date
0         A 2022-10-16
1         A 2022-10-17
2         A 2022-10-18
3         A 2022-10-19
4         B 2022-10-16
5         B 2022-10-17
6         B 2022-10-18
7         B 2022-10-19
8         C 2022-10-16
9         C 2022-10-17
10        C 2022-10-18
11        C 2022-10-19
```